# Running apps on remote machine using current user credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access

I'm using `enter-pssession` to connect to a remote machine via Powershell. I then try to run an application via this connection on the remote machine. However, when I do this, it believes the user is anonymous and I get permission errors.

I'd like the app to either run as the current user I used to remote from, or be able to provide the credentials that it can run under. I see a whole bunch of authentication options for the `enter-pssession` cmdlet but it's not clear to me what I need to use.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There's another problem here. You should never be able to establish a Powershell Remoting session anonymously. Never. Something is misconfigured here.

Comment: What's also weird is that when I type `[Environment]::UserName` while remoted, it displays the correct user name.

Comment: @MgSam Can you provide an example of the error message and the command that you are running in the remote session? If you are attempting to run a command through the remoting session that requires permissions to a network resource then the default configuration will normally prevent double hop scenarios. You should research CredSSP or RunAs accounts if you need this type of behaviour. Otherwise let us know the details so we can help you out.